# Google not indexing my vbulletin forum

Tags: indexing, google-search, google-search-console

I have submitted sitemap at google webmastertools & showing 'Web pages 945,657 Submitted'

its 3 days gone, but still not indexing.

Even no error appear.

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of reasons as to why it isn't being indexed yet, one of the reasons can be the cleanliness of the URL, e.g:

`www.example.com/Blog/id=12&name=Blog%20name&ref=`

looks a lot worse than something like:

`www.example.com/Blog/Blog-Name`

Other possible reasons: [here](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/definitive-list-reasons-google-isnt-indexing-site/118245/)